# Restrict selector to a Set of Elements (jquery object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, jquery-selectors

I am looking for this sort of functionality: `$(restrictTo).findAlsoSelf('.box').doSomethingWithTheMatches()`

where `restrictTo` is a jquery object([a jQuery object represents a set of DOM elements](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)). So I only want my selectors to apply to the set of elements defined by the `restrictTo` argument.

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only works for the children of each element. I also need the element itself to try to get matched.

## [Demo: jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/6SgWC/)

The demo uses the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method which you might say I could just write

`$(document).on('click', '.box', function() { ...`

to get the functionality I am looking for. **BUT** I do not want to double bind or mess up content that may already be loaded.

The `.color-box` is a good example of this. I only want the one I just added to turn yellow. The one already at the bottom of the page and at the top of `.content` should stay green.

---

The closest I can come up with is:

`$(restrictTo).find('.color-box').add($(restrictTo).siblings('.color-box')).doSomethingWithTheMatches()`

But this also matches any siblings already in that dom level (see the `.color-box` in the `.content` area of the demo.

Maybe I over thought this way too much. I thought I was really familiar with jQuery, but I just can't come up with a clean solution.

The actual project utilizes [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) with requireJS plugins for handlebars templates and css. All of the code becomes modular. So once a template gets rendered, I need to bind and add the javascript to go along with that snippet. I do have an attach method where I called `require(['modules/tiny-module/tiny.bits']);` but the problem is if I need load in the `tiny-module` more than once, the `tiny.bits.js` script only executes once when it gets loaded into the page when the `tiny-module` is loaded for the first time and never gets attached to the newly loaded dom.

Once I figure out this `restrictTo` thing I will basically call the `bind()` method in the attach method of each module which will actually execute on every consecutive loading of the module.

---

Edit: My answer didn't solve it but I just want to document it. It doesn't work with [this edge case](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/YKPju/).

```
jQuery.fn.findAlsoSelf = function(selector) {
    return this.find(selector).add(this.filter(selector));
};
```

@phenomnomnominal answer is great and works with both demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
jQuery.fn.filterFind = function(selector) { 
    return this.find('*')         // Take the current selection and find all descendants,
               .addBack()         // add the original selection back to the set 
               .filter(selector); // and filter by the selector.
};
```